# not a valid identifier Mac OS Terminal returning an error every time I open it. Related to PATH variable?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, path

the following comes up everytime I start a new terminal session.

-bash: export: `/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Users/user1/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/user1/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin': not a valid identifier

then I am unable to use many commands or initiate a python session. cd command still works. I understand it may be related to the PATH variable and .bash_profile file? It started happening after unsuccessfully installing mysql (my os is not right version).
I am very new to all of this so any help would be amazing thank you!

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage or troubleshooting; [Superuser](https://superuser.com/), the [Unix & Linux stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com), or even [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) are better places for questions like this. All already have a a number of similar questions, but probably none that match the exact problem you have. You will have to do some troubleshooting to figure out what the specific problem you have, and which shell startup file it's in.

Answer (score 0):

Search and check the `export` instructions on your `.bash_profile`. You probably miss the variable assignation like that:

```
export PATH="${PATH}:...path to add..."
```

You'll probably find something like:

```
export "$PATH:..."
```

Which give you this error.